# What is C.O.T movement index and how do I calculate it?

Tags: technical-analysis, commodities

I just read the **The Commitments of Traders Bible: How To Profit from Insider Market Intelligence** by Stephen E. Briese.

It was great and introduced me to the **C.O.T index** and how to calculate it but I couldn't figure out how to calculate **C.O.T movement index** using the **C.O.T index**.  Can anyone here  show me how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search provides the following

> The **COT Index** highlights extremes in trader net positions. The rate of
>   change of the COT Index or **COT Movement Index** is simply the difference
>   between the **COT Index** and its reading of one or several weeks prior.
>   The Movement Index marks three intermediate reaction highs (arrows),
>   which initially provided excellent reselling points and subsequently
>   became ideal levels for trailing stop losses.

Quote from [Wiley Online Library](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781119201861.ch7)

So there is a choice of how many weeks 'n' back in time you compare with. I would suggest some back testing of this with varying values of 'n', to determine if what n gives you the best reaction for your market.

Answer (score 1):

One claim to fame of Larry Williams is the Williams %R Indicator.  In reality, it's the inverse of George Lane's Stochastic Indicator so he didn't really invent anything at all with this indicator.

Larry Williams also wrote a book about the COT Report.  Out of curiosity, I took a quick look and found this explanation:

https://freecotdata.com/how-to-use/

It looks like a variation of the %R Indicator, adjusted for Open Interest.  Beyond that, I have no clue nor am I going to research this for you.  And unfortunately, this is probably going to be the best answer your receive since it's likely to be the only answer :->)

Comment: hey , i did not ask about how to use the COT data , am just trying to figure out how Briese calculated the COT movement  so am asking about the math formula more then technical indicator

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Marcus is correct. I simply want to add that in Briese's book he specifies that he uses a value of 6 weeks (this from memory reading the book some years ago). I tested this against the COT Charts found on Briese's website and this confirms my memory.

COT_Index(movement) = COT_Index(current) - COT_Index(-6 weeks)

Briese simply highlights the -+40 moves as crimson red. Here is a link to the Australian dollar chart [on his site](https://commitmentsoftraders.org/wp-content/uploads/Static/AD_OPT.png).